# Numpy: Can't search for tuple in list

Tags: python, list, numpy, tuples

I am trying to search for a tuple in a list

```
import numpy as np
l = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (3, 4)]
print(np.where(l == (0, 0)))
 >>>> (array([], dtype=int64),)
```

It's not possible for some reason. It's weird to me, because `l[0]` returns `(0, 0)`

Comment: do you really need numpy here? A simple list comprehension would work

Comment: It's just part of a big file.. But thanks for the suggestion  :D

Comment: Are you finding all, or just the first?  Is it really a list of tuples, not some sort of array?  And how big of a list.  Beware of `numpy` approaches when a simple list method (like `index`) will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

To achive what you seems you are after with vectorized code you need to cast `l` (or `(0, 0)`) to a NumPy array and use `np.all(..., axis=1)`:

```py
import numpy as np
l = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (3, 4)]
print(np.nonzero(np.all(np.array(l) == (0, 0), axis=1))[0])
# [0]
```

---

You should probably take a step back and try to understand the single pieces of your code.

1. Your input is a `list`. The equal operator `==` on a list act on the whole list will give you either `True` or `False` depending on whether the two lists contain the same elements.
2. `np.where()` without further options (which should be avoided in favor of `np.nonzero()`) will look for non-zero entries in your array and return the indices of such entries.

Hence, `np.where()` on a scalar boolean will return either `(array([0]),)` or `(array([], dtype=int64),)` for `True` or `False` respectively.

If you were to use `==` on a NumPy array the result would still be different from what you expected, essentially because `==` will work element-wise in this case (eventually broadcasting the arguments). For example:

```py
a = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]])
b = np.array([0, 1])
a == b
# [[ True False]
#  [False  True]
#  [False False]]
```

To obtain what you are after with vectorized code you would need to find the rows where the values are *all* `True`, effectively collapsing/reducing one dimension/axis with `np.all(..., axis=...)`, e.g.:

```
a = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]])
c = np.array([0, 0])
np.all(a == c, axis=1)
# [ True, False, False]
```

which would essentially check that all elements in along axis 1 are `True`.

Now, you can use `np.nonzero()` to find the indices:

```
np.nonzero(np.all(a == c, axis=1))[0]
# [0]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need to work with NumPy, a simpler approach is to just loop through the list.

Assuming the input as:

```py
l = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (3, 4)] * 2
x = (0, 0)
```

One such implementation could be:

```py
def search_all(items, x):
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        if item == x:
            yield i


print(list(search_all(l, x))
# [0, 3]
```

If the list is sufficiently sparse, it may be faster to loop through the list using the `list.index()` method, which forces some of the iteration through faster pathways.
This is essentially implemented in [FlyingCircus](https://pypi.org/project/flyingcircus/) `index_all()`.

```py
def index_all(seq, item):
    i = 0
    try:
        while True:
            i = seq.index(item, i)
            yield i
            i += 1
    except ValueError:
        return


print(list(index_all(l, x))
# [0, 3]
```

Both methods above are very memory efficient, and reasonably fast.
For faster implementations, one could use Cython to accelerate the explicit looping.

As @KellyBundy suggests, it is even possible to do all the looping implicitly:

```py
import itertools
import operator


def search_all_iter(seq, item):
    return itertools.compress(
        itertools.count(),
        map(operator.eq, seq, itertools.repeat(item)))


print(list(search_all_iter(l, x))
# [0, 3]
```

---

If the inputs are NumPy array (and hence the conversion to NumPy array is not needed), and we can start from `al`/`ax`:

```py
import numpy as np


al = np.array(l)
ax = np.array(x)
```

then vectorized approaches (which however require reasonably large temporary objects) such as `find_index_np()` (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72110523/5218354)) or `find_index_unique()` (borrowed from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72110298/5218354)) can be devised:

```py
def find_index_np(arr, subarr):
    return np.nonzero(np.all(arr == subarr, axis=1))[0]


print(find_index_np(al, ax))
# [0 3]
```

```py
def find_index_unique(arr, subarr):
    return np.unique(np.array(list(zip(*np.nonzero(arr == subarr))))[:, :1])


print(find_index_unique(al, ax))
# [0 3]
```

Alternatively, it may be possible to write memory efficient and fast approaches working well with NumPy arrays using Numba acceleration:

```py
@nb.njit
def all_eq(a, b):
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        if x != y:
            return False
    return True


@nb.njit
def find_index_nb(arr, subarr):
    result = np.empty(arr.size, dtype=np.int_)
    j = 0
    for i, x in enumerate(arr):
        if all_eq(x, subarr):
            result[j] = i
            j += 1
    return result[:j].copy()


print(find_index_np(al, ax))
# [0 3]
```

---

Finally, please find some benchmarks for the above:

```py
l = ([(0, 0)] + [(1, 1)] * 9) * 1000
x = (0, 0)
al = np.array(l)
ax = np.array(x)


%timeit list(index_all(l, x))
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 500 µs per loop
%timeit list(search_all(l, x))
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 911 µs per loop
%timeit list(search_all_iter(l, x))
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 701 µs per loop
%timeit find_index_np(al, ax)
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 247 µs per loop
%timeit find_index_unique(al, ax)
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 1.41 ms per loop
%timeit find_index_nb(al, ax)
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 465 µs per loop
```

Note that all these approaches are `O(N)` in time complexity (their computation time increases linearly with the size of the input), but their relative speed depends heavily also on how often the item being searched is found, e.g. if we increase the occurrences of `x`/`ax` from one every ten to one every two then `index_all()` becomes slower than `search_all()`:

```py
l = ([(0, 0)] + [(1, 1)]) * 5000
x = (0, 0)
al = np.array(l)
ax = np.array(x)


%timeit list(index_all(l, x))
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 1.22 ms per loop
%timeit list(search_all(l, x))
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 1.01 ms per loop
%timeit list(search_all_iter(l, x))
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 666 µs per loop
%timeit find_index_np(al, ax)
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 250 µs per loop
%timeit find_index_unique(al, ax)
# 100 loops, best of 5: 6.91 ms per loop
%timeit find_index_nb(al, ax)
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 483 µs per loop
```

Comment: The "itertools version of `search_all`" [seems to do well](https://tio.run/##fVLNSsQwEL73KeaYaFm6iKBCj76BeBEpsZ26gfztNMXu06@ZpFoXxRxKyHw/028mnOLBu5u7QOeztsFThKgt6liN5C303hjso/ZugrU84HHGUtURKXpvvmuEAVWsE80Gwmni2@xWLR@QVPT0BcZjVQ04woSK@kOnjBFJ0CbSIh8qSGdkcM02ycsButmyBBbcCuKjxwJqW1i2Vz4njWYAXZy0G3DJRhMei@4qoqGFJt8inTaFj4M2CE8046Uqw5PELgvmbpKa/NP4knbdwj4/4dJjiPCszIyPRJ42A8I4k1s7Lgl7DvlX0wX4HbbIWQtZg1VBMDYTykxyk1LKqhpn10@5/6/Y6y2Y@sKxSrk2xcskhngRTQ2NfIVreBH7GvbpegX3Mn32TVPyWxiYYRWaCf9nM/P2DyYPvuORk3LvKG5@7AO3z5X8G1toMZGtdqIs7279aaPs26Aeys4KpgjD68UmNaR1ekNqU@tym10gnUJMO8zoXdc5ZbHrSr3U5Pn8CQ), too.

Comment: It is indeed interesting to see how an approach with fully implicit looping will fare, thanks!

Comment: Isn't it cheating to test the numpy solutions with arrays instead of the **list of tuples**?

Comment: Uhm, it is just assuming one is starting from NumPy array inputs instead of lists. Of course, if that is not the case one would need to consider some additional time for conversions.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, if we want to use numpy, let's ensure that we are working on a proper ndarray:

```python
#I add some more data for test purposes
l = np.array([(0, 0), (1, 1), (3, 4), (3, 6), (0,0)]) 

> array([[0, 0],
         [1, 1],
         [3, 4],
         [3, 6],
         [0, 0]])
```

Afterwards, I recommend using `np.nonzero` in order to find all the indices that respect a certain condition, the problem is that it seems like numpy is unpacking the tuple and giving me indices to each of the tuples' elements if the tuple respects the condition, to circumvent this, we just pick the first dimension of the index and apply `np.unique` to get rid of the duplicates.
(I suspect there is a  much more elegant solution that I am obviously missing).

the final result is:

```python
np.unique(np.array(list(zip(*np.nonzero(l == [0,0]))))[:,0:1])

> array([0, 4], dtype=int64)
```

do note that, as commenters have suggested, the solution is probably more readable in a list comprehension format:

```python
#We avoid using an ndarray since we will be using vanilla python anyway
l = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (3, 4), (3, 6), (0,0)]
l_indx = [i for i, tup in enumerate(l) if tup == (0,0)]

> [0, 4]
```

Comment: The `np.unique()` approach may be even slower than simple looping.